# Unable to install a package with NPM ... gets stuck at chokidar@1.7.0

Tags: angular, npm, command-line-interface

I am trying to install `@angular/cli` using npm. But it always gets stuck while downloading the package `chokidar`:

[image]

Diagnostic info:

```
npm version 5.0.0
node version 8.0.0
Operating System Windows 7
```

Comment: how long have you waited for it to complete. Sometimes it just needs more  time

Comment: Try doing npm cache clean

Comment: I waited for more than 10 hours. I cleaned my system and reinstalled node but same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolve this issue by myself. I had multiple temp variable in the environment variable (system) which was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue by run command prompt using administrator permissions and its working fine. Look at the image attached.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXsfz.png

Answer (score -1):

Please upgrade your `node` and `npm` versions to latest. After that please follow the below steps to install the `angular/cli`:

1) Open your command prompt with administrative privileges and uninstall `angular/cli` by using `npm uninstall -g angular-cli` command.

2) You can try deleting `node_modules` from your project directory and then clear the cache by using `npm cache clear --force` command.

3) Remove `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\` and `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`.

4) Try to install the `angular/cli@latest` by using `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` command.